# How can I insert multiple empty cells, if a certain criteria is met?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm currently stuck trying to figure this out. Basically, I'm trying to insert an amount of  empty cells only when cells from A2:B2 return a value. I got it to work where if both cells are empty one empty cell gets moved in. But I need both cells to move down if the criteria is met.

```
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("A2:A").moveTo(sheet.getRange("A3:A"));
  sheet.getRange("A2").setValue();
}

function insertSecondCell() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("B2:B").moveTo(sheet.getRange("B3:B"));
  sheet.getRange("B2").setValue();
}

function onEdit()
{
  let values = currentsheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  let secondvalues = currentsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  if((values && secondvalues) != "")
  {
    insertSecondCell();
    insertCell();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Range.insertCells()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcellsshiftdimension), like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
* Inserts one blank cell under A1 and B1, pushing cells A2:B2 and below down.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.rowStart !== 2
    || e.range.columnStart > 2
    || !sheet.getName().match(/^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  const inputRange = sheet.getRange('A2:B2');
  const values = inputRange.getDisplayValues().flat();
  if (values.every(value => value.length)) {
    inputRange.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }
}
```

Note that the `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that runs *every* time *any* value in the spreadsheet is edited. It makes sense to minimize the number of API calls in the code, and use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e` whenever possible.

If you want to insert *rows* instead of *cells*, take a look at the [autoInsertRowAtTopOfSheet_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/73783836?msgid=73796266) script.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So I added your code                                                                       `function onEdit(e)
{
  let values = currentsheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  let secondvalues = currentsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  if ((values && secondvalues) !== '') 
  {
    e.range.getSheet().insertRowAfter(2);
  }` But its not moving the values on A2 and B2 down, also wouldn't `.insertRowAfter()` insert a complete row? I'm just looking to move the values to a certain location if a criteria is met

Comment: Edited the answer to meet your requirements. Modify the `Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3` regex to specify which sheet(s) you want the function to insert cells. Please edit your question to make it clear that you want to insert _cells_ rather than _rows_.

Comment: It works! Thanks, I edited my original post.